# unable to change fullcalendar event color ('fc-event-inner' CSS) (used under JIRA)

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, jira

I went through other posts related to fullcalendar event color but it couldn't work for me.

I tried below

```
 calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
                                        id: resp[i].ID,                                         
                                        title: resp[i].desc,
                                        start: s,
                                        end: e,
                                        allDay: true,
                                        comments: resp[i].comments,
                                        className: ["event",  "greenEvent"],
                                        eventColor: '#378006'   
                                    }
```

Also, tried by applying at calendar object:

```
    disableDragging: false,
            eventColor: '#378006',              
            //eventBackgroundColor: 'red',

                     eventClick:...
```

But this just make the events border color change but it does not change the event's background color change.
Event's background color remains white only...

I have found, it uses - '.fs-event-inner' as a CSS which override runtime. I tried by changing at firebug and it shows event color changed.
But, when I tried to dynamically change color through below, then it did not applied and work.

```
 AJS.$('.fc-event-inner').css({"background":"red"});
```

Can any one please suggest me how it could be resolve and get the background color changed for events.

I am using this fullcalendar in JIRA.

Comment: Any one has idea on this, i am still facing an issue ?

Comment: 2 questions, 1. What version of full calendar are you working with? 2. Are you trying to color all of the events, all of the events depending on event source, or just a single event?

Comment: version is FullCalendar v1.6.0. I want to change all events color. I tried by applying at calanedar object : eventColor: 'couleur',          
          eventBackgroundColor: 'couleur', but it just change the border. Can you please provide stuff which i missed to use.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you use to create the calendar, including event sources? This is probably where you will want to specify the color.

Comment: Actually, have you tried in your `renderEvent` object to just set `color: '#378006'`, instead of `eventColor: '#378006'`?

Comment: @Shaded if i change "color"  then also, it just applies to border. when apply as - background or backgroundcolor or css at renderEvent then no any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My friend, I had the same problem.
I'm using *fullCalendar 1.6.1* and *jquery ui 1.10.3*

I just did this and worked for me, I hope will work for you.

when I create the fullCalendar, I use the callBack "eventRender".

```
$('#my_cal_div').fullCalendar({

  ...

  ,eventRender:function(event,element){

  element.children('.fc-event-inner').css({'background-color':'yellow'});
  element.children('.fc-event-inner').css({'border-color':'blue'});
  element.children('.fc-event-inner').css({'color':'red'});

}

...

}); //end of fullCalendar constructor...
```

At least, It worked for me.

Saludos !

Leonardo Oporto.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms - for me, the inclusion of fullcalendar.print.css was overriding the coded colors.  You probably only want the print.css including when you are actually printing, which sort-of makes sense.